# How to display the file contents recursively?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls, cat

I always have to submit the source codes in my printed assignment report. **I have to copy and paste my course codes** into the document and I find that it is an annoying task.

I want to solve this **"copy and paste"** problem. Therefore I did it with `cat` like that but it only works in the current directory. I hope it can display the file contents recursively.

```
ls -R *.java | xargs cat >> all_course.txt
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `find` ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)) to accomplish this:

```
find -name "*.java" -exec cat {} \;
```

You can also add a `-print` before the `-exec` to print the file name before each cat operation

Comment: Adding `| vim -` in the end will allow you to navigate/grep through text and also highlight syntax if needed, so `find . -name "*.java" -exec cat {} \; | vim -`

Comment: To see the file name and to see more easily where a file ends: `find "$1" -type f -print -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "###" \;`

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

Comment: The `{} \;` is not needed after cat ... those are used only in find's `-exec` command.

Comment: ^^ Right. corrected...

Answer (score 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/*.java >> all_course.txt
```

That all_course file will be a bit of a mess. You probably want to add in some headers or footers:

```
for f in **/*.java; do
    echo "/* *********************************"
    echo " * $f"
    echo " * *********************************/"
    echo ""
    cat "$f"
    echo ""
    echo "/* *********************************"
    echo " * $f"
    echo " * *********************************/"
    echo ""
    echo ""
done > all_course.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 grep -R -win --include='*\.java' '' * | less
```

Will show line no. also, for easy reading. Manipulate with grep switches for better results.